# php remove value from array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I need help in removing values from an array using a recursive function

```
$array = [0] => testing,testing1
[1] => testing,testing1,testing2
[2] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3
[3] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[4] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[5] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[6] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[7] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
```

I need to check the array count, ie `if count(array[0]) == count(array[1]),then reutrn array
else unset(array[value]);`

From the above array I have to remove `array[0],[1],[2]` and return rest of the array values.

I've tried the below code

```
$idx =10;
$separtor =',';
function array_delete($idx, $array,$separtor) {
  $finalvalue = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $idx; $i++) {
   $values = explode($separtor, $array[$i]);
   $valuesnext = explode($separtor, $array[$i+1]);
       if(count($values) != count($valuesnext) )
       {
            unset($array[$i]);
           // reset($array);
           // array_delete($idx, $array,$separtor);
            if (is_array($array)) $array = array_delete($idx, $array,$separtor);
            $finalvalue =  $array;
       }else
       {

       }
    //echo $i;

}
return $finalvalue;
//(is_array($array)) ? array_values($array) : null;
//array_delete($idx, $array,$separtor);
}
```

I'm getting `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 when trying calling recursive, going to infinite loop`

Comment: Your code only contains a single function but not how you invoke it (that function just deletes array members for a criteria it does not talk about).

Comment: Do you mean that you want a filtered array, where each value must be at least as big as the one that follows it? Or just that each element must be the size of the final array?

Comment: you just removed nearly your whole question. What are you aiming for a re-wording? - Ah no, you aim for duplicating questions. Please do not duplicate questions, as you try to hide it, -1 even you've got puppy protection: duplicate is here: [recursive function to remove array values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11107079/367456) - Also take care, this question in the current form might get closed as not a real question, too. In any case, continue to edit this one, not the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to keep the sub-arrays that have the most items? Your descriptions appear to say this.

If so, something like the following would suffice.

```
// Get maximum number of items in the arrays
$max_count = max(array_map('count', $array));

// Keep only those arrays having $max_count items
$filtered  = array_filter($array, function ($a) use ($max_count) {
    return count($a) === $max_count;
});
```

<sup>Aside: if you need the filtered array to have zero-based keys, call `array_values()` on it.</sup>

See [an example running online](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xOB7qY).

Comment: I'd say only the last matches should match. With your example data, the outcome would be an empty array. But I'm not really sure as the question is a bit imprecise, let's wait for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the array such that any value in the final array is of the same length as the last element in the source array. In order to avoid mutating an array while iterating over it, this technique builds a fresh array with the elements that match your criteria.

```
$matchLength = count($mainArray[count($mainArray) - 1]);
$resultArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($mainArray); $i++) {
    if(count($mainArray[$i]) == $matchLength) {
        $resultArray[] = $mainArray[$i];
    }
}
```

If you happen to be using PHP 5.3 or greater, you can do this quicker with closures and array_filter:

```
$matchLength = count($mainArray[count($mainArray) - 1]);
$resultArray = array_filter($mainArray, function($element){return count($element) == $matchLength});
```

Double check the code, I haven't been writing PHP lately, so this is just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description you gave, it could be just made (check the count of the current and the provious one, if they don't match, remove the previous one).

Example/[Demo](http://codepad.org/Pk5Yilwr):

```
unset($prevKey);
$count = array();
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    $count[$key] = count($array[$key]);
    if (isset($prevKey) && $count[$prevKey] !== $count[$key]) {
        unset($array[$prevKey]);
    }
    $prevKey = $key;
}
```

If you need to re-iterate to take removals into account, a little goto can do the job [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AkBEob):

```
start:
######
unset($prevKey);
$count = array();
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    $count[$key] = count($array[$key]);
    if (isset($prevKey) && $count[$prevKey] !== $count[$key]) {
        unset($array[$prevKey]);
        goto start;
        ###########
    }
    $prevKey = $key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and helping to solving the issue

Comment: how to make this as recursive function to unset previous value

Comment: This works as a stack, so you don't need to make it recursive normally. It does already unset the previous value.

Comment: $array = array(
    array('testing', 'testing1'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'),
    array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'),
);
i need to apply this on above array

Comment: @user1465259: What should be the outcome? Should the values with a count of 2 be preserved? This is how it currently works: http://codepad.org/tgSdqRck

Comment: all the array element should be same ,ie array('testing', 'testing1', 'testing2', 'testing3', 'testing4'); elements should only be 5 not less then 5

Comment: output [0] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[1] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[2] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[3] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4
[4] => testing,testing1,testing2,testing3,tesing4

Comment: Okay, this can be still done with the stack, but needs re-iteration on  unset. In PHP 5.3 a little goto should do the job, I updated the answer.